# VPN setup for remote access on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: vpn, ufw, strongswan, ubuntu-18.04

I have successfully setup a vpn server using this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-ikev2-vpn-server-with-strongswan-on-ubuntu-18-04-2
.
(but using pre-shared key, not username/password)
I can now connect from a client, and but I cannot access apache running on the server.

My UFW settings block all incoming traffic except port 22 and 500,4500/udp.
How can i setup strongswan/ufw to allow connections to apache over vpn? 
To clarify: I only want to allow connections over vpn, not direct.

Comment: When you run `$ sudo ufw status verbose` from the Ubuntu server, do you have Apache status as "Allow anywhere"? and are you getting any errors?

Comment: I don't have an "Allow anywhere rule", because I only want to allow connections to apache over VPN not direct. (I have edited my post as this might have been unclear). But seems like the firewall is blocking connections to port 80 (no errors, just no response).

Comment: Warning: Use a more secure authentication method with IKEv2. PSK is weak and may be insecure (saw it in a Snowden document).